# Weird issue with matrices from package Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I get an unexpected error when dealing with 0 column or 0 row matrices in the package Matrix.
One of my function can be sometimes called with degenerated inputs and it has to multiply matrices with some having 0 lines or column.
The product is MxI with I being 0x1 and M nx0. The expected result is a nx1 Matrix of zeros.
I and M both come as a dense matrices (dgeMatrix).
The product gives me random results as if they were some memory leak somewhere.
Here is a code that will reproduce my bug:

```
library(Matrix)
I = as(Matrix(0,0,1),"dgeMatrix")
M = as(Matrix(0,10,0),"dgeMatrix")
M %*% I
M %*% I #should be the same as above but it is likely to be different
summary(sapply(1:1000, function(...)max(abs(M %*% I))))
```

The problem does not arise if the matrices have more than 1 row or 1 column or if the class of the Matrices are dgcMatrix. The workaround is to coerce the inputs to dgcMatrix.
Anyone ever faced the same problem?

Cheers!
Seb

Comment: You perhaps are not aware of machine precision limits. Try loading some legal values and dimensions.

Comment: Better yet, force your function not to prodce zero-row matrices, as they don't really make any sense in the first place. Failing that, reject any matrix which meets the criterion `any(dim(my_matrix)%in% 0)`

Comment: I do not see why this would come from a machine precision issue. The result of the multiplication of a Nx0 and 0xP should be a NxP matrice of zeros (empty sums everywhere).
I was only pointing out changes at every call and is not what we expect.
The workaround is trivial but makes things a bit tedious.